# Simulink models comparison issue

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm comparing two simulink models and in the report i'm getting the following difference. I don't really figure out what that difference is. Any idea is appreciated

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to compare and what are you seeing that is different? I can't tell from your images what you are asking about. Please be more specific.

Comment: @hazzey - I wonder where I can find "SimulationSettings -> InstrumentedSignals" in a simulink model.